# Kind of flyout module on my help-page with FAQ Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to make a helppage on my Drupal website.
I could easily make this by posting 20 Questions and putting a link behind it to a PDF or another webpage that has the information.
But I want something fancy. I want some kind of flyout module.

Example:

NORMAL STATE
How to add a picture?  <-- USER CLICKS
How to add a PDF?

CLICKED STATE
How to add a picture?
   If you want to add a picture go to "add resources" on your page and choose a picture...
   Click here for a PDF-example.
How to add a PDF?

CLICKED ON ANOTHER QUESTION
How to add a picture?
How to add a PDF?
   Bla bla bla bla.

I hope it is clear to you guys what I want. I can't really find a module to do something like this because I don't know how to call it. It isn't really a flyout like from a menu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No drupalgeeks available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get what you mean (although I'm not 100% i do!) I think you can achieve what you want with the field collection module and a bit of jquery:

https://drupal.org/project/field_collection

So you'd create a field collection - '20 questions' with fields for question, answer, pdf download etc.

attach it to a content type of you choice.

use css to hide the answers and jquery to show them when a user clicks a question.

Pretty much exactly what's done on this page: http://tdpf.org.uk/resources/glossary-terms